# Get Row data associated with max value after pivoting the df using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the pandas dataframe which look like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    'col2': ['test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test2', 'test2', 'test2',
             'test2', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5',
             'test1', 'test1'],
    'col3': ['t1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1',
             't1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't1'],
    'col4': ['input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input4', 'input1', 'input2',
             'input3', 'input4', 'input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input5',
             'input2', 'input6', 'input1', 'input1'],
    'col5': ['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2',
             'result3', 'result4', 'result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4',
             'result2', 'result1', 'result2', 'result6'],
    'col6': [10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 50, 20, 100, 10, 10],
    'col7': [100.2, 101.2, 102.3, 101.4, 100.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 102.0,
             87.0, 107.0, 110.2, 120.0, 88.0, 106.2, 101.1]
})

ptable = df.pivot_table(values='col7', index=['col4'], columns=['col2'], aggfunc='max')

ptable = (ptable [(ptable >= 100).any(1)]
        .fillna('')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

I am trying to retrieve the row data associated with the max values once the data is pivoted on col2. The data which i am interested is col5 and col6 data but not able to figure out how to get that information. Any input is much appreciated.

The two output tables i am looking for are as follows:

Requested Output Table#1:

| col4 | col5 | col6 | test1 | test2 | test3 | test4 | test5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| input1 | result2 | 10 | 106.2 |  |  |  |  |
| input1 | result1 | 10 |  | 100 | 102 |  |  |
| input2 | result2 | 20 | 101.2 | 103 | 87 | 120 |  |
| input3 | result3 | 30 | 102.3 | 104 | 107 |  |  |
| input4 | result4 | 40 | 101.4 | 105 |  |  |  |
| input5 | result4 | 50 |  |  | 110.2 |  |  |

Requested Output Table#2:

| col4 | col5 | col6 | test1 | test2 | test3 | test4 | test5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| input1 | result2 | 10 | 106.2 |  |  |  |  |
| input1 | result1 | 10 | 102.2 | 100 | 102 |  |  |
| input2 | result2 | 20 | 101.2 | 103 | 87 | 120 |  |
| input3 | result3 | 30 | 102.3 | 104 | 107 |  |  |
| input4 | result4 | 40 | 101.4 | 105 |  |  |  |
| input5 | result4 | 50 |  |  | 110.2 |  |  |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update include greater than 100:

```
ptable = df.pivot_table(values='col7', index=['col4', 'col5', 'col6'], columns=['col2'], aggfunc='max')
ptable_1 = ptable.where((ptable.groupby(level=0).rank(ascending=False) == 1.)&(ptable>100)).dropna(how='all')
print(ptable_1)
```

Output:

```
col2                 test1  test2  test3  test4  test5
col4   col5    col6                                   
input1 result1 10      NaN    NaN  102.0    NaN    NaN
       result2 10    106.2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
input2 result2 20    101.2  103.0    NaN  120.0    NaN
input3 result3 30    102.3  104.0  107.0    NaN    NaN
input4 result4 40    101.4  105.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
input5 result4 50      NaN    NaN  110.2    NaN    NaN
```

And,

```
ptable_2 = ptable[((ptable.groupby(level=0).rank(ascending=False) == 1.).any(axis=1))&(ptable>100).any(axis=1)]
print(ptable_2
```

Output:

```
col2                 test1  test2  test3  test4  test5
col4   col5    col6                                   
input1 result1 10    100.2  100.0  102.0    NaN    NaN
       result2 10    106.2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
input2 result2 20    101.2  103.0   87.0  120.0    NaN
input3 result3 30    102.3  104.0  107.0    NaN    NaN
input4 result4 40    101.4  105.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
input5 result4 50      NaN    NaN  110.2    NaN    NaN
```

---

IIUC, try:

```
ptable = df.pivot_table(values='col7', index=['col4', 'col5', 'col6'], columns=['col2'], aggfunc='max')
ptable_1 = ptable.where(ptable.groupby(level=0).rank(ascending=False) == 1.).dropna(how='all')
print(ptable_1)
```

Output:

```
col2                 test1  test2  test3  test4  test5
col4   col5    col6                                   
input1 result1 10      NaN  100.0  102.0    NaN    NaN
       result2 10    106.2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
input2 result2 20    101.2  103.0   87.0  120.0    NaN
input3 result3 30    102.3  104.0  107.0    NaN    NaN
input4 result4 40    101.4  105.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
input5 result4 50      NaN    NaN  110.2    NaN    NaN
input6 result1 100     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   88.0
```

And,

```
ptable_2 = ptable[(ptable.groupby(level=0).rank(ascending=False) == 1.).any(axis=1)]
print(ptable_2)
```

Output:

```
col2                 test1  test2  test3  test4  test5
col4   col5    col6                                   
input1 result1 10    100.2  100.0  102.0    NaN    NaN
       result2 10    106.2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
input2 result2 20    101.2  103.0   87.0  120.0    NaN
input3 result3 30    102.3  104.0  107.0    NaN    NaN
input4 result4 40    101.4  105.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
input5 result4 50      NaN    NaN  110.2    NaN    NaN
input6 result1 100     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   88.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. How can I input the criteria of only to report col7 if it is greater than 100.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. One follow-up question, is there a way to populate NaN with say "Col4 data is missing" or "Col5 data is missing" or "Col4 & Col5 data is missing".

Comment: @buggsbunny4 I don't follow the logic here.  From the input dataframe add nan for data that isn't there?

Comment: what i meant to say was, instead of populating the output table with NaN/blank for missing data, I would like to know if it is possible to replace "NaN" in the final output table with something like "Col4 data is missing" or "Col5 data is missing" or "Col4 & Col5 data is missing" depending on the situation. What I am trying to do is tell the end user, why  some cells are blank and provide them with which combination is missing. For example for the first row of the output table, input1-result1 row for test4 column, instead of saying "NaN", i would say "Col4 & Col5 data is missing"

Comment: @buggsbunny4 In this case, all values would be "Col4 & Col5 data is missing" This particular structure of the data doesn't alow for NaN with just Col4 or Col5 missing, I don't think.

Comment: True for most cases but not all For example if we look at test2/test3 columns,both those columns does have input1 data identifier but it is lacking result2 identifier hence the resulting output was NaN. so in this case for input1-result2, test2/test3 columns would be populated just by "Col5 data is missing". But for test4 column input1-result2 row,test4 does have "result2" identifier but is lacking "input1" identifier.so in the case of input1-result2, test4 column would be populated by "Col4 data is missing". Hope i am making sense on what i am trying to achieve here.

Comment: I am sorry, @buggsbunny4.  I am just not getting how you determine Col 4, Col 5 or both are missing.

Comment: thanks for taking time for looking into it for me. let me see if i can explain it any better. i am just looking at the raw data itself. for example if we take test4 column, it contains [input2] in col4 and [result2] in col5 values. So, when we are looking at row input1-result2 combination for test4 column, i compare if input1 is in col4 dataset and if result2 is in col5 dataset for test4 data. So, in this case, result2 is in col5 dataset but input1 is not in col4 dataset.  so i flag "col4 is missing"

Comment: Okay, I think I see.  Would you mind going ahead and accepting this solution, create a new question with ptable_2 as your input and show your expected output for the first few rows.

Comment: This should be a new question because it requires considerable additional logic.